# facebook page plugin only shows text with name of page

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to add the Facebook Page Plugin on my webpage. Unfortunately, nothing shows up except for the text: "facebook". I added the code they gave me on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ exactly as it should be. Here is an example of the code I added to a blank .HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-----------THIS IS THE FIRST STEP(just pasted the code FB gave me)------------>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<!-----------THIS IS THE SECOND STEP(just pasted the code FB gave me)------------>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Theres nothing wrong with the added code.. Is there something additional I should add or do? This widget links to facebook's facebook page. When I link it to my page, it does the same thing(just shows the text "corecoders"). All page plugins only show text.

Comment: Are you testing your page via a local webserver, so that it gets called via HTTP in the browser? Otherwise, the protocol-relative URL for the SDK, `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/…` can’t work. (Unless you explicitly prefix it with `http:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xampp or Mamp for the LOCAL WEBSITE fixed the problem. When hosted it works perfectly though.